# How long does it take for Salesforce to build the SOSL index?

Tags: sosl

After adding new data to Salesforce, the records do not show up immediately in SOSL queries or  the Salesforce search interface.  How long does it take for new information to be indexed?

I'm looking for answers that quote specific documentation or offer your empirical experience for likely ranges of time.  Thanks!

Comment: related lists don't use sosl.

Comment: For this question, let's say one new record added in real-time.

Comment: Anecdotally, it's 90 seconds or so for me in most cases.

Comment: Normally its pretty fast (around a minute), but it also depends on the amount of data you have in the org.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOSL is basically running queries against [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), so you may want to look for info on Solr data-indexing times (and account for some Salesforce-related possible overhead).

[Proof that Salesforce.com uses Solr](http://www.igvita.com/2010/10/22/open-source-search-with-lucene-solr/), in case you didn't totally believe it. :)

Comment: Solr data indexing for a single document (SFDC record) is near-instantaneous (source: having run several Solr/Lucene projects). The lag you see in SOSL is 99% attributable to SFDC shared infrastructure/overhead.